# What happens when two selectors have the same deck colour?

Tags: wixoss

When Selectors battle, there is a large wheel or clock that decides which Selector goes first.

The Selectors are represented by their deck colour (eg. Yuzuki - Red Deck, Ruko - White Deck)
The image below is from when Ruko battled Yuzuki, And it's clear that Ruko gets to go first.

But how could we tell who goes first if both Yuzuki and Ruko had the same coloured deck? Would the wheel be entirely one colour?

As of season 1 of the anime there have been no same-deck battles but maybe there is some external source of information about this?

[image: Wheel of selection]

Comment: FWIW, the actual real-world card game uses rock-paper-scissors to determine who goes first, so we're not going to find any answers there.

Comment: Maybe they have a slightly different shade of red.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In episode 11 of Selector Spread WIXOSS, There is a same-coloured battle:

> between Mayu & Ruuko (Black vs Black)
>  [image]

It seems like when the selectors are battling with the same deck colour, they can choose who goes first.

This also ties into the real game - where there are no hard set rules on which player goes first. (although I presume this advantage is offset in some way)